# System Design - Amazon Product Checkout Flow

Tags: architecture

I am designing a system that has the same logic to be applied as it for product checkout in Amazon. Let me explain the problem with reference to Amazon.

A newly release product, say a phone, has limited stock in Amazon, say 1000 units. It is being release at 9 AM today. Now for buying any product in Amazon, when you are in the product page, you can click the "Buy Now" button. This will take you to the Checkout page (that contains the receipt along with delivery address and payment method detailed out). The checkout page has the "Pay Now" button, on clicking which it will invoke the payment gateway to start the payment process. 
Now I only want payment to happen for 1000 units only and no more.
This is to be kept in mind too that the first 1000 person to click on the "Buy Now" wont end up making the payment and even if many of them start the payment process, their payments might fail and have to do over again.
How do I design such a system such that no payment is initiated without guarantee of availability of stock. Assume its a sale and that 100X number of people are visiting the website in the first minute for the product. (X = Number of units available)

Answer (score 0):

1. Transactionally create an order, which decrements the available stock as soon as they click the "Buy Now" button
2. Have a process that comes along behind to free up all the ones that never went all the way to completion.  Say, five minutes after the "Buy Now" button is clicked, release the product back to the pool, cancel the order, and increment the available stock.

This will result in potential lost sales.  The alternative is to pick a later step to decrement the available stock, and have fewer lost sales, but more potentially angry customers who can't complete the order.